# Generar un bucle multifile import para exportar a una carpeta que se cree con el nombre del documento si son 1 o muchos documentos

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp

El motivo de mi pregunta es para saber como generar un bucle correspondiente para exportar archivos que pueden ser uno o Muchos desde un MultifileUpload, cuando se haga la exportación correspondiente cada archivo debe quedar en una carpeta tipo /UploadedFiles/aaaa/aaaa.pdf, hay cosas que podria agregar como un create directory pero pregunto como generar el bucle que si cargo un archivo me genere /UploadedFiles/aaaa/aaaa.pdf pero si son muchos cada archivo tenga su carpeta correspondiente con el documento correspondiente ejemplo:

Si llegan 3 archivos me genere una exportación por archivo como lo siguiente:
/UploadedFiles/aaaa/aaaa.pdf - /UploadedFiles/aaaa1/aaaa1.pdf - /UploadedFiles/aaaa2/aaaa2.pdf

Quedo atento a sus respuestas, muy agradecido y adjunto codigo correspondiente:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

 // GET: Home
 public ActionResult UploadFiles()
    {
        return View();
    }
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFiles(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
    {
      //Ensure model state is valid
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {   //iterating through multiple file collection 
            foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
            {
              //Checking file is available to save.
                if (file != null)
                {
                  var InputFileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                  var ServerSavePath = 
                  Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/") + 
                  InputFileName);
                  //Save file to server folder
                   file.SaveAs(ServerSavePath);
                  //assigning file uploaded status to ViewBag for showing 
                  //message to user.
                    ViewBag.UploadStatus = files.Count().ToString() + " 
                    Archivos correctamente subidos.";
                }
           }
      }

     return View();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya tienes el bucle lo unico que debes hacer es indicarle a c# como se llamara la carpeta

```
var InputFileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
var FolderName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);

Directory.CreateDirectory("/tu-ruta/" + FolderName);

var ServerSavePath = 
              Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/") + FolderName + "/"
              InputFileName);

file.SaveAs(ServerSavePath);
```

Comment: Genera el siguiente error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso.

var InputFileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        var FolderName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
                        Directory.CreateDirectory("~/UploadedFiles/" + FolderName);
                        var ServerSavePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/") + "/" +
              InputFileName);

Comment: Son varias las causas por las que puede dar ese error, y varias las formas de solucionarlo, puede ser que IIS no tenga permisos, puede ser que tu usuario no tenga permisos, o que la aplicacion no tenga permisos. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43941461/11023698

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya pude solucionarlo igual tengo otra consulta pero la agregare como otra pregunta